# Stop a GenServer after each test

Tags: elixir, gen-server, ex-unit

### Background

I have a set of tests that need a GenServer to be started before. As a rule of thumb, I understand it is a good practice to cleanup after each test, so I also want to stop the GenServer after each test.

### Problem

The problem here is that I don't know how to stop a GenServer after the test has finished. I always end up with some concurrency issue.

```
defmodule MyModuleTest do
  use ExUnit.Case

  alias MyModule

  setup do
    MyModule.Server.start_link(nil)
    context_info = 1
    more_info = 2
    %{context_info: context_info, more_info: more_info}
  end

  describe "some tests" do
    test "returns {:ok, order_id} if order was deleted correctly", context do
      # do test here that uses created server  and passed context
      assert actual == expected

      #clean up?
    end
  end
end
```

Now, I have tried [`on_exit`/2](https://hexdocs.pm/ex_unit/ExUnit.Callbacks.html#on_exit/2) like the following:

```
  setup do
    {:ok, server} = MyModule.Server.start_link(nil)
    context_info = 1
    more_info = 2
    
    on_exit(fn -> GenServer.stop(server) end)

    %{context_info: context_info, more_info: more_info}   
  end
```

But i get this error:

```
** (exit) exited in: GenServer.stop(#PID<0.296.0>, :normal, :infinity)
         ** (EXIT) no process: the process is not alive or there's no process currently associated with the given name, possibly because its application isn't started
```

I have the feeling this is exiting too soon.

I also tried using [`start_supervised`](https://hexdocs.pm/ex_unit/ExUnit.Callbacks.html#start_supervised/2) however since my `GenServer` has a lengthy initialization in `handle_continue` the tests run before the server is ready.

### Question

How can I fix this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I finally figured out what was going on.

Turns out `start_supervised` is working as expected and is in fact **waiting for the GenServer to end `handle_continue`** (well, it is not *exactly* waiting, it still sends messages and these are put into the queue waiting for the proper time to get executed).

The issue here was the fact that I didn't do a full cleanup from all the stuff I initiated in my `handle_continue`. Turns out some of the connections and processes I started remained even after the original GenServer died.

The solution was two-folded:

- catch all stop signals
- once a stop signal is detected, do a graceful shutdown

In code, this is translated into:

```
def init(_) do
    Process.flag(:trap_exit, true) # trap all exits!
    {:ok, %{}, {:continue, :setup_queue}}
end

def handle_continue(:setup_queue, state) do
   # do heavy lifting
    {:noreply, state}
end

def terminate(_reason, state), do:
    # undo heavy lifting
```

With this and `start_supervised` inside my `setup` block, everything works nicely.

Comment: Interesting! What connections and processes survived the death of the GenServer?

Comment: In my case, I was using a library called :jobs, https://github.com/uwiger/jobs .
The created queues wouldn't be deleted after the process that created them died. So I had to do it manually.